# Storing selected emails from outlook in SQL Server by forwarding

Tags: sql, sql-server, outlook, outlook-addin

This may not be possible but just wanted to see if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I am building a system that needs to store all corespondence between the company and each client.

Is it possible to forward an email from outlook to a certain email address that will then store this email in an SQL server.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: SharePoint provides such a feature ([Configure incoming e-mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx)).

Comment: There are several parts to this question that could be researched and/or asked separately. How reliable does this have to be? What if Outlook isn't running because the recipient went on vacation? You may need a solution at the mail server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Outlook Add-on: www.geniusconnect.com

Link Sent Items Outlook Folder to your table and check "Auto Save" option. This will save sent items automatically to DB.

Comment: Thanks for that, yes think Outlook add-on is the way to go, I also found this (http://www.email2db.com/email-to-database.aspx) a little while ago so will take a look into both options.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an outlook add-on using .NET that inserts the contents of the e-mail into a SQL Server table and the sender information.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at it the other way around.  Build your email in the database first, then have a separate process actually send out the emails.  After every successful send, you mark database email record as "sent".

I recommend an asynchronous approach.  As emails are to be sent, they are generated and stored in an EmailQueue table.  Another process monitors the EmailQueue table and sends out the emails as it discovers them.  This way any delay with the actual sending of email will not interfere with the process that is generating the emails to be sent.